# Display WordPress search results based on the selected Sub-Category

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to create a search using dropdowns in WordPress.

I've got two dropdowns, 1 - Parent Category and 1 - Sub-category.

The Sub-category will show automatically based on the selected Parent category.

My goal is to have the 2 dropdowns with a submit button and have it act as a search, displaying the selected sub-category's posts on the results page.

I've got this far using research but I'm completely lost and struggling as you can see.
Below is my functions.php code used for the search:

```
    // FUNCTIONS.PHP

    // Drop-down Ajax call

    add_action('wp_ajax_my_special_action', 'my_action_callback');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_special_action', 'my_action_callback');
    function my_action_callback() {
        if(isset($_POST['main_catid'])) {
            $categories = get_categories('child_of='.$_POST['main_catid'].'&hide_empty=0');
            foreach ($categories as $cat) {
                $option .= '<option value="'.$cat->term_id.'">';
                $option .= $cat->cat_name;
                $option .= ' ('.$cat->category_count.')';
                $option .= '</option>';
            }
            echo '<option value="-1" selected="selected">Search...</option>'.$option;
            die();
        } // end if
    }



    // Define search for sub-category
    function search_filter( $query ) {
        // only modify your custom search query.
        if ( $query->is_search &&  $_post['my_search'] == "c_search") {
            $args = array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => array( $_post['main_cat']),
                    'operator' => 'IN'
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => array( $_post['sub_cat']),
                    'operator' => 'IN'
                )
            );
            $query->set( 'tax_query', $args);
        }
        return $query;
    }

    // The hook needed to search_filter
    add_filter( 'the_search_query','search_filter');
```

This is the HTML & JS code used for the form and Ajax call for the sub-categories:

```
 <!-- BODY HTML CODE -->
    <div id="content">

    <!-- Search form-->
    <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">
      <div>
        <input type="text" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
        <?php
    wp_dropdown_categories('show_count=0&selected=-1&hierarchical=1&depth=1&hide_empty=0&exclude=1&show_option_none=Main Categories&name=main_cat');
    ?>
        <select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat" enabled="disabled"></select>
        <input type="hidden" id="my_search" name="my_search" value="c_search" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="search" />
      </div>
    </form>


    <!-- Dropdown Ajax call script -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function() {
          jQuery('#main_cat').change(function() {
            var $mainCat = jQuery('#main_cat').val();

            // call ajax
            jQuery("#sub_cat").empty();
            jQuery.ajax({
              url: "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
              type: 'POST',
              data: 'action=my_special_action&main_catid=' + $mainCat,

              success: function(results) {
                //  alert(results);
                jQuery("#sub_cat").removeAttr("disabled");
                jQuery("#sub_cat").append(results);
              }
            });
          });
        });
    </script>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`the_search_query` filter is not for that purpose. Use `pre_get_posts` filter instead.

Try this code:

```
// Define search for sub-category
function search_filter( $query ) {
    // only modify your custom search query.
    if ( $query->is_search && !is_admin() && $_post['my_search'] == "c_search" ) {
        $args = array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array( $_post['main_cat']),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array( $_post['sub_cat']),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $args);
    }
    return $query;
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_filter' );
```

Comment: is WordPress search.php page supposed to have a hook for this code too in order to display what was selected? I've tried the above code but my search results still show all post and none relevant to what was selected

Comment: `pre_get_posts` is for that purpose. There might be 2 cases if above code isn't working.

CASE 1: Remove the main category from `$args` because you only want to show the posts of sub category.
OR
CASE 2: Try to change if statement: `if ( !is_admin() && is_search() )`